# MySQL select row with specific conditions and last inserted row for those conditions in many to many

Tags: mysql, many-to-many

I have 3 tables with many-to-many relation. I want to select for specific user and specific product last inserted row for this product.

Table 'user' contains personal info of user:

```
userID     persID     firstName     lastName     gender
42         9559000    Jane          Rae          female
43         9559001    John          Doe          male
.
.
.
```

Table 'storage1' contains product information:

```
storageID     product     productAttribute     productSize     storageQTY
1             shirt       red                  S               10
2             shirt       blue                 M               10
.
.
.
13            shirt       green                L               10
14            shirt       green                XL              9
15            shirt       green                XXL             7
.
.
39            trousers    male                 60              10
40            trousers    male                 62              8
.
.
59            shoes       standard             41              10
60            shoes       standard             42              7
61            shoes       standard             43              10
62            shoes       standard             44              10
63            shoes       standard             45              9
.
.
72            jacket      red                  L               10
73            jacket      red                  XL              9
74            jacket      red                  XXL             6
```

and table activityRecords:

```
recordsID     userID     storageID     startDate     expDate
99            43         15            2017-09-14
100           43         74            2017-09-14
101           43         39            2017-09-14
102           43         13            2017-09-14
103           43         14            2017-09-14
104           43         40            2017-09-14
105           43         14            2017-09-14
106           43         63            2017-09-14
107           43         59            2017-09-14
```

So far I have this code which result only the max value of product related to specific user.

```
select 
        persID, 
        firstName, 
        lastName, 
        gender, 
        max(case when storage1.product = 'shoes' then storage1.productSize end) shoes, 
        max(case when storage1.product = 'trousers' then storage1.productSize end) trousers, 
        max(case when storage1.product = 'shirt' then storage1.productSize end) shirt, 
        max(case when storage1.product = 'shirt' then storage1.productAttribute end) color, 
        max(case when storage1.product = 'jacket' then storage1.productSize end) jacket, 
        startDate, 
        expDate 
    from activityRecords 
        left join user on activityRecords.userID = user.userID 
        left join storage1 on activityRecords.storageID = storage1.storageID  
    where persID='9559001' 
    group by persID, firstName, lastName, gender, startDate, expDate
    order by persID
```

which result this:

```
persID     firstName     lastName     gender     shoes     trousers     shirt     color     jacket     startDate     expDate
9559001    John          Doe          male       45        null         null      null      null       2017-09-14
9559001    John          Doe          male       null      62           null      null      null       2017-09-14
9559001    John          Doe          male       null      null         XXL       green     null       2017-09-14
9559001    John          Doe          male       null      null         null      null      XXL        2017-09-14
```

but I want to get this:

```
persID     firstName     lastName     gender     shoes     trousers     shirt     color     jacket     startDate     expDate
9559001    John          Doe          male       41        null         null      null      null       2017-09-14
9559001    John          Doe          male       null      62           null      null      null       2017-09-14
9559001    John          Doe          male       null      null         XL        green     null       2017-09-14
9559001    John          Doe          male       null      null         null      null      XXL        2017-09-14
```

because shoes number 41 is the latest entry for shoes in activityRecords table (recordsID 107) and shirt size XL is the latest entry for shirt in activityRecords table (recordsID 105).
While right now there is for shoes selected recordsID 106 and shirt select is recordsID 99. I know that this is related because of my select code (using max(case when...)), but I don't know how to select most recent entry for specific product and person. Anyone can help me with this? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to you to proceed with sub-queries or views in order to get your result more easily.

[Views Syntax Reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-view.html)

You could create a view for each product such as:

```
create view shirt_activity_view
as select
  ar.userID,
  ar.recordsID,
  s1.productSize as shirt,
  s1.productAttribute as color,
  ar.startDate, 
  ar.expDate   
from activityRecords as ar
  inner join storage1 as s1
    on ar.storageID = s1.storageID
   and s1.product = 'shirt';
```

If you want to get the latest *shirt activity* for all user:

```
select
  *
from shirt_activity_view
inner join (
    select
      userID,
      max(startDate) as max_start_date
    from shirt_activity_view
    group by userID
  ) as max_dates
  on shirt_activity_view.userID = max_dates.userID
 and shirt_activity_view.startDate = max_dates.max_start_date
```

You could use this last query as a new view or as a sub-query in a more complex query.

In this way, you could even get a flatten structure for all your data (using all the columns you are expecting in your result set)

Comment: it shows more than one last row, but it's ok for me. thanks